# Distance measure for two probability distribution of unequal sample size

Tags: distributions, normal-distribution, similarities, kullback-leibler, distance-functions

Context: I have 100 stores and these stores are divided into 10 business markets. I want to select 3 markets where each market is a good representation of the 100 stores i.e. the population.

There are 5 variables like revenue, population density based on which the markets will be called similar.

I thought of comparing the probability distribution of each variable in the market with the corresponding probability distribution of all the 100 stores combined(chain level).

So for example if market A has 15 stores under it and revenue is the variable in consideration then compare the probability distribution of these 15 stores to the 100 stores.

Generate a distance similarity measure and sum this measure for all the variables. The top 3 markets having the most similar value to the chain level should be the selected markets.

The problem I am facing is that the probability distributions are having unequal length i.e. length of market A is 15, while length of all stores will be 100, so I am unable to use KL divergence or jensenshannon as they seem to work on distribution having equal sample size.

I have to questions:

1) Is the approach I am following a good approach.

2) If yes what similarity measure should i use.

Comment: Good question. This is a pretty common scenario. Here's a paper that formulates a hypothesis test for such a situation:

Bhattacharya & Valiant, Testing Closeness With Unequal Sized Samples (NIPS 2015)

https://papers.nips.cc/paper/2015/file/5cce8dede893813f879b873962fb669f-Paper.pdf